Can I say "Would've been that funny hadn't been that sad"
Can I say the next sentence:
Would've been that funny hadn't been that sad.
in the meaning "It would have actually been funny, unless it had been as sad as that" (a situation was both funny and sad, but more sad than funny) ?

In some varieties of English you might, but not in mine.

You could try saying that, but people might give you odd looks. You could maybe say 'It would have been funny if it wasn't sad'. Is your question about conditionals, the past perfect and simple past tenses, or something else?

@MichaelHarvey My question is about a way to say ironically that a situation is actually sad, even though it looks like a funny one. I thought I could use that sentence for that.

Shall we take your question seriously?  Your avatar photo suggests it might be a joke.  Your "sentence"  lacks a subject in the first clause.

@TimR It's not a joke. I've seen a similar construction in the book called "Pollyanna", here's the quote: "And he wheeled about and stalked from the room with a dignity that would have been absurd had it not been so pitiful." I tried to construct a sentence in this way. Please disregard my avatar, it's just a bit of self-irony.

@TheIIIWorldman Your proposed phrase is substantially different from the book. If you had fully mirrored the phrase, it would have worked: "The situation would have been funny had it not been so sad."

Some notes: 1) "hadn't" is a contraction of "had not." You can't use it if another word, like "it," has to come between "had" and "not." 2) Pollyanna is more than 100 years old. "Had it not been" sounds a bit dated today, and "if it hadn't been" would be more contemporary.


And he wheeled about and stalked from the room with a dignity that would have been absurd had it not been so pitiful. (from OP's comment)

"with a dignity that would have been absurd had it not been so pitiful"
is another way of saying "with a dignity that would have been absurd if it had not been so pitiful".

The party went late into the night. Had my alarm not gone off, I would have slept until noon.
The party went late into the night. If my alarm  had not gone off, I would have slept until noon.


Thanks, now I get it. So the sentence I was trying to construct is "It would've been funny, had it not been that sad".

@TheIIIWorldman  Yes, you understand how "had {something} not" is used.  A minor point: "that sad" assumes you have already mentioned how sad it was, whereas "so sad" can be used to state for the first time that it was very sad.

"The boat was bigger than my garage. Had it not been that big, I would have bought it."

"The airplane hangar is so big!"   (good).  "The airplane hangar is that big!"  (ungrammatical unless you've already said something about how big it was, perhaps comparing it to a football stadium).

Unless, of course, you were looking right at it and the reference is to your impression of it when you saw it:  "I didn't know a bison was going to be that  big."

This isn’t a complete sentence:

Would've been that funny hadn't been that sad.

"It would have actually been funny, unless it had been as sad as that." is also unclear.
Edit 3
Depending on the meanings you want to convey, you may say
It would have been funny if it wasn't so sad.
It wouldn’t have been (that) funny if it wasn't that sad.
Edit 2 In Response To The OP’s Comment
There are some adjectives suggested in this link which you may consider.  We could say
This is a tragicomic situation.

Why wouldn't you use the simple past for the second part?

Thanks, @Michael Harvey.  Yes, simple past is better. I've edited my answer.

Is there a way to describe a situation that looks funny, but in fact is sad? I was wondering if there was a short sentence for that purpose. It seems the sentence I wrote in the question isn't a correct option.

@The III World man, I've added some points to my answer.

"As sad as that" is a little unidiomatic in this situation. I think the usual construction is "It would have been funny if it wasn't so sad."

Thanks, @YonKuma. I've changed 'as sad as that' to 'so sad'.  As the second pair of sentences became very similar to the first, I decided to delete one of the pairs.

Would've been that funny hadn't been that sad.
A simple edit does the job.
It would've been that funny if it hadn't been that sad.
